# how to interpolate a variable into string method

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I have a public static class Entity with string variables

```cs
public static string entityName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["entity.name"];
```

I need to call this to my test

```
[TestCase(Data.User.userType.ClientUser,Data.Enitity.entityname)]
```

when I call this into my test, I'm getting the error `An Attribute argument must be a constant expression.`

How to get the entity.name from a Data.cs?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot pass variables to attributes, they need to be constant.

Secondly, it looks like you're using NUnit so instead of using `TestCase`, you can use `TestCaseSource`. See the docs [here](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData).

So you first need a class to return your data:

```
public class MyDataClass
{
    public static IEnumerable TestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(Data.User.userType.ClientUser,
                                          Data.Enitity.entityname);
        }
    }  
}
```

And your `TestCase` attribute is replaced with:

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(MyDataClass), "TestCases")]
```